# Converting line, echo within an echo in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, echo

so I looked through a number of similar topics here and couldn't for the life of me replicate the techniques to this.

I'm working Wordpress and instead of adding the following line:

```
<a class="button alt live_demo" href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_live_demo', true ); ?>">Live Demo</a>
```

..directly into Wordpress template files, I'm trying to hook in via functions.php. So first I added the function to the hook where I want it to go:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_live_demo_link');
```

Then created the function:

```
function add_live_demo_link() {
echo '<a class="button alt live_demo" href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_live_demo', true ); ?>">Live Demo</a>';}
```

Obviously that code won't work, can anyone help converting that to a working function?

Comment: Did you by any chance forget to escape the quotes around `_live_demo`? Like so: `... $post->ID, \'_live_demo\', true ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues with your code. 1. you are not globally declaring `$post` so you'll never retrieve any meta. 2. You are echoing an echo, which will probably also not work.

I didn't test this so I may have made a typo, but this is on the right track:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_live_demo_link');
function add_live_demo_link() {
    global $post;
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_live_demo', true );;
    printf( '<a class="button alt live_demo" href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $meta ), __( 'Live Demo', 'my-plugin' ) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Appied this via functions and solved the issue.